# How to set the value of an object inside another list object in the flutter

Tags: flutter, list, dart, object

In my app, I need to get some data and storage them and finally show them in graph. So, I have defined some class as follows:

```
class DurationTime {
  StatisticalParam p24H;
  StatisticalParam p1W;
  StatisticalParam p1M;
  StatisticalParam p1GD;
  DurationTime(this.p24H,this.p1W,this.p1M,this.p1GD);// to create getter : Alt+Insert
  factory DurationTime.fromMap(Map data) =>  DurationTime(data['p24H'],data['p1W'],data['p1M'],data['p1G']);
}
class StatisticalParam {
  TimeValuePair max;
  TimeValuePair min;
  TimeValuePair avg;
  TimeValuePair latest;
  List<TimeValuePair> timeSeriesData = List<TimeValuePair>.filled(5760,TimeValuePair(0,0));//<TimeValuePair>[];
  StatisticalParam(this.min,this.max,this.avg,this.latest,this.timeSeriesData);

  factory StatisticalParam.fromMap(Map data) => StatisticalParam(data['max'],data['min'],data['avg'],data['latest'],data['timeSeriesData']);
}
class TimeValuePair{
  TimeValuePair(this.value,this.time);
  double value;
  double time;

  factory TimeValuePair.fromMap(Map data) => TimeValuePair(data['value'],data['time']);
}
```

`Then I defined a list with name of instDevice, and  initialize it as follow:`

```
List<DurationTime> instDevice = List<DurationTime>.filled(11,
    DurationTime(StatisticalParam(TimeValuePair(0,0), TimeValuePair(0,0), TimeValuePair(0,0), TimeValuePair(0,0),List<TimeValuePair>.filled(5760,TimeValuePair(0,0))),
        StatisticalParam(TimeValuePair(0,0), TimeValuePair(0,0), TimeValuePair(0,0), TimeValuePair(0,0),List<TimeValuePair>.filled(5760,TimeValuePair(0,0))),
        StatisticalParam(TimeValuePair(0,0), TimeValuePair(0,0), TimeValuePair(0,0),TimeValuePair(0,0),List<TimeValuePair>.filled(5760,TimeValuePair(0,0))),
        StatisticalParam(TimeValuePair(0,0), TimeValuePair(0,0), TimeValuePair(0,0),TimeValuePair(0,0),List<TimeValuePair>.filled(5760,TimeValuePair(0,0)))));
```

When I want to assign value to
`instDevice.elementAt(Index).p24H.latest.value`
for `Index=1`, it is changing for all `Index=0` to `11` not only `Index=1`!!
Please let me know, how I can set `instDevice.elementAt(Index).p24H.latest.value` for special `Index`?

Please let me know, how I can set `instDevice.elementAt(Index).p24H.latest.value` for special `Index`?

Comment: The code you posted does work: https://dartpad.dev/?id=aeb09f0e8187542c1a7e30d65be3cc37

Comment: Yes instDevice.elementAt(1).p24H.latest.value = 42.0 is true, But instDevice.elementAt(2).p24H.latest.value and instDevice.elementAt(3).p24H.latest.value and ... become 42.0 too! I don't want value of instDevice.elementAt(2).p24H.latest.value to instDevice.elementAt(11).p24H.latest.value to change!

Answer (score 0):

Any reason this doesn't work?  I might be misunderstanding the issue:

```
instDevice[index].p24H = newValue;
```

Comment: When I assign
instDevice.elementAt(0).p24H.latest.value = newValue
Value of 
instDevice.elementAt(1).p24H.latest.value 
and
instDevice.elementAt(2).p24H.latest.value 
...
instDevice.elementAt(11).p24H.latest.value
set to newValue! But I don't want their value to change.

Comment: Can you clarify?  You seem to be saying that you're trying to set the value to a new value, but you don't want the value to change.  I'm not sure why you are using latest.value.  Did you try assigning the way I specified?

Comment: Depending on how you are assigning the values of the original object. If all your StatisticalParam are set to the same value...that's a pointer, not unique values.  So you will be changing all the other params when you change the one.  You can either rebuild an entirely new DurationTime or you will need to set the original values uniquely.  What I mean is if instDevice[index].p24H = newValue; and instDevice[index].p1W= newValue; (off same variable).  Changing newValue will change both p24H and p1W...because they are pointing, not unique.

Comment: Dear jbryanh, I changed the way variable instDevice is defined as follows: List<DurationTime> instDevice = new List<DurationTime>.generate(11,...); But my problem still remains and when I assigned value to instDevice[0].p24H.latest, the amount of instDevice[1].p24H.latest, instDevice[2].p24H.latest,... and instDevice[11].p24H.latest also changes!

Answer (score 0):

`List.filled` will use the same instance for every position. You need a new instance in each position otherwise, yes, you'll update *the shared instance* in every position. Instead of using `List.filled`, use [`List.generate`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.3/dart-core/List/List.generate.html)

```dart
  List<DurationTime> instDevice = List<DurationTime>.generate(
    11,
    (i) => DurationTime(
      StatisticalParam(
        TimeValuePair(0, 0),
        TimeValuePair(0, 0),
        TimeValuePair(0, 0),
        TimeValuePair(0, 0),
        List<TimeValuePair>.filled(
          1,
          TimeValuePair(0, 0),
        ),
      ),
      StatisticalParam(
        TimeValuePair(0, 0),
        TimeValuePair(0, 0),
        TimeValuePair(0, 0),
        TimeValuePair(0, 0),
        List<TimeValuePair>.filled(
          1,
          TimeValuePair(0, 0),
        ),
      ),
      StatisticalParam(
        TimeValuePair(0, 0),
        TimeValuePair(0, 0),
        TimeValuePair(0, 0),
        TimeValuePair(0, 0),
        List<TimeValuePair>.filled(
          1,
          TimeValuePair(0, 0),
        ),
      ),
      StatisticalParam(
        TimeValuePair(0, 0),
        TimeValuePair(0, 0),
        TimeValuePair(0, 0),
        TimeValuePair(0, 0),
        List<TimeValuePair>.filled(
          1,
          TimeValuePair(0, 0),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Comment: Dear Nico Spencer, thank you for your response, I defined instDevice as you said. But I can not set just instDevice[0].p24H.latest, and all instDevice[1:11].p24H.the latest set to a value assigned to instDevice[0].p24H.latest! Please let me know how I must set the value to just instDevice[0].p24H.latest.

Comment: It sounds like you need them to be independent, as well as also assigning them the same value at times.  Nico is correct in needing to generate your list independently to avoid your pointer problem, and in that situation, you'll need to use an for loop or something to assign your bulk values.